# Module only installs to Python 2 and I can't access it from Python 3

Tags: python, python3

I'm trying to install wxPython on macOS and I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed in parallel.

I've written a wxPython Hello World program in both versions. It works in Python 2, but in Python 3 I get this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'.

It seems wxPython was only installed to Python 2.7 and Python 3 can't find it. How can I make it accessible from both versions?

Comment: Related: [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/7246614)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I reinstalled python 3.7 then installed wxPython. A quick reboot (not sure if that was even needed) and all is now working.

Answer (score 0):

The [official instructions for installing wxPython](https://www.wxpython.org/pages/downloads/) say

> #### Windows and macOS
>
> ```
> pip install -U wxPython
> ```
>
> If you are on Windows or macOS with a compatible Python build, then the command shown above will download the appropriate wheel file from the latest release, and **install it in your active Python environment** or virtual environment.

As the wording hints to, this command only installs `wxPython` for your default python version. (In this case, that seems to be Python 2.)

Just like the command `python` is an alias for either `python2` or `python3`, the command `pip` is an alias for either `pip2` or `pip3`. If you want to make sure that you install a module for both versions of Python, you should run both commands:

```
pip2 install -U wxPython
pip3 install -U wxPython
```

However, this solution is **not recommended** because it doesn't work with all python versions. Instead, [it is recommended](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/) to use `python -m pip` with your preferred version of python:

```
python2 -m pip install -U wxPython
python3 -m pip install -U wxPython
```

See also: [Dealing with multiple python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/7246614)